# Exception 0x80040154 generated while executing a simple ssis package in MS SQL 2008R2 enviornment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Hello I tried executing a simple SSIS package. Basicall I am reading a flat source file, sorting it on id and again writing in a new flat source file destination. But when I execute i get following exception:

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Failed to start project

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

### Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

I browsed through lot of forums and mostly they focused on 32-bit 64 bit issue and insisted on reinstalling the MS SQL server again. I am not sure about this exception since its a commonly generated error for different scenarios and issues. Just wanted to know if anybody has faced a similar issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception was being generated primarily because, I was trying to run a 32 bit SSIS package on 64 bit environment. So Solution for this to simply change one of the properties value "Run64BitRunTime" by setting it to false. You can find this in properties of solution present under solution explorer

Answer (score 0):

Take the .dtsx file and create a copy in another location. Create a new project and add this file to the new project. Try and run the package again.

Comment: It is giving me the same issue. looks like there is some problem with connection

Comment: I dont think its gonna work for you. Did you try running the package on another machine?

Comment: acutally I am on my office machine and we have a dedicated server for the same. But one of my peer colleagues tried running some different package on his own machine (an office laptop) and he faced same error.

Comment: So, are you running the package on your "Dedicated Server" or your local SQL Installation? If you cannot run any other package on the said box, probably the installation has corrupted and you may want to re install the entire suite. But, my initial thought would be to test the package in a different environment.

Comment: the sql is installed on the server itself and i am accessing through remote connection. Even I think it might be some installation issue. just need to confirm. thanx for your help. I really appreciate it.